# Not found .Net core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017 community edition

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition 2017 and installed .net core 2 sdk but 2.0 is missing in visual studio.

I am wondering that i can create .net 1.o and 1.1 core web application but there is no 2.0. Seems like it is missing.

Comment: When you really installed the 2.0 sdk correctly it should show up in the New WebApplication dialog, in a combobox.

Comment: Maybe do a reinstall and watch for error messages.

Comment: Is your Visual Studio 2017 installation updated to at least `15.4`?

Comment: thanks @GeorgDangl, after installing Visual Studio 2017 15.4, I can create core 2 Web applicaiton